# Is there an option for log models for every k epochs in MLflow autolog?

Tags: pytorch, mlflow

I'm wondering if there is an option to log models for every k epoch in MLFlow **autolog**?
When I used `mlflow.pytorch.autolog()`, the logged model is only one and I'm guessing that would be the one of the last epoch.

Or should I do it manually after every k epoch using `mlflow.log_model`?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbVgG.png)

Answer (score 0):

With PyTorch lightning, you can use a custom callback as follow :

https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/callbacks.html

In this callback you can log every thing you want. Here an example with Keras (you can do the same with PyTorch) :

https://databricks.com/blog/2019/08/19/mlflow-tensorflow-open-source-show.html

Comment: Can you add a few lines to explain the content of these links